# Background video is playing over screen on iphone mobile browsers

Tags: css, iphone, html, bootstrap-4

I have added a video in the background using html5 tags:

```
<video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" id="bgvid" poster="/assets/food/home/banner.jpg" muted>
    <source src="http://38.89.136.40/videos/eatwedovideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
```

It is working fine, but sometimes when we click on the background it starts play on the screen like as normal video play and then we need to click on done and its disappear from the screen.
I want to take this video only in background instead playing on screen.

Please suggest a way to handle this type of problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this adding `playsInline` and `webkit-playsinline` on video tag, and remember, don't add `controls` tag. This solution play video inside container, for example:

```html
<video autoPlay loop muted playsInline webkit-playsinline>
  <source src="path/to/your/video" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Regards :)

Answer (score -1):

Use this link:

You should use css to fix video in background see here:

https://slicejack.com/fullscreen-html5-video-background-css/

**Demo:** http://dev2.slicejack.com/fullscreen-video-demo/index.html

Comment: tested on iPhone 14, did not play